# I am trying to create a graphql mutation , where i cannot add the categoryNode as a input feild to AddEquipment mutation

Tags: django, mongodb, graphene-django

**category model**
this my category model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Category node**
I've created a category node using relay

```
class CategoryNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        filter_fields = ['name', 'equipments']
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

**add equipmemt mutation**
while mutation i need to add a category object to equipment object in mutation inputs

```
class AddEquipment(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        category = graphene.Field(CategoryNode)

    equipment = graphene.Field(EquipmentNode)

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, **inputs):
        equipment_instance = Equipment(
            name=inputs.get('name'),
            category=inputs.get('category')
        )
        equipment_instance.save()
        return AddEquipment(equipment=equipment_instance)
```

by this code iam getting error like this

"AssertionError: AddEquipmentInput.category field type must be Input Type but got: CategoryNode."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that as an `ObjectType` cannot be an `InputObjectType`. The only way for you to make it work is to create a new class which derived from the `InputObjectType`.

```
class CategoryInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(required=True)
    name = graphene.String()
```

and use it.

```
class AddEquipment(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        category = graphene.Field(CategoryInput, required=True)

    ...
```

> UPDATE

I think in your case, If you only want to get the category instance there would be no point to input a whole detail of category in your mutation so I suggest to only input the `name` and the category `id` in your inner `class Input` and get query a category instance [see example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) inside your `mutate_and_get_payload`.

So to be precise you should refactor your code into:

```
class AddEquipment(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        category_id = graphene.ID(required=True)

    equipment = graphene.Field(EquipmentNode)

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, **inputs):
        # if ID is global make sure to extract the int type id.
        # but in this case we assume that you pass an int.
        category_instance = Category.objects.get(id=inputs.get('category_id'))
        equipment_instance = Equipment(
            name=inputs.get('name'),
            category=category_instance
        )
        equipment_instance.save()
        return AddEquipment(equipment=equipment_instance)
```

Comment: this is my mutataion 

mutation{
  addEquipment(input:{name:"test equipment",category:{name:"server equipments",id:"5d9a2231e1c4888946342b4d"}}){
    equipment{
      name
    }
  }
}

Comment: Your error is from here `equipment_instance = Equipment(
            name=inputs.get('name'),
            category=inputs.get('category')
        )` the category only accept category instance rather than an object.

Comment: yea bro , i cannot find a documentation to pass an instance of an object in graphiql

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide me an example to pass an instance of an object to mutation. TIA @Roel

Comment: Bro, thanks for the update, i am unable to resolve the errors.
`graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "equipments_equipment" ("name", "description", "category_id") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s)
Params: ['test equipment', 'rfbejvbjt', ObjectId('5da8a6deb0023da01550eff1')]
Version: 1.2.36`

Comment: Like i said in my answer you need to convert the global id which is a string you pass into `category_id ` to int type. I suggest before you dive into this stuff please read the documentation as it is very helpful.